# How to run tomcat as a service on windows

Tags: windows, windows-services

**I executed the service.bat file in the Tomcat_home/bin directory, Tomcat could not be accessed, I go to the log and check, I get the below error.**

> 23-May-2023 07:43:36.758 INFO [Thread-12]
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading
> Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped
> already. Could not load [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy].
> The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as
> to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application
> instance has been stopped already. Could not load
> [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy]. The following stack trace
> is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate
> the thread which caused the illegal access.       at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1385)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1373)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1226)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
> at
> ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.(LoggingEvent.java:119)
> at
> ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:419)
> at
> ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
> at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.error(Logger.java:538)         at
> com.arcturus.utils.Log.error(Log.java:141)        at
> com.arcturus.reports.scheduler.ApplicareSchedulers.initializeApplicareReportQuartzScheduler(ApplicareSchedulers.java:188)
> at
> com.arcturus.reports.scheduler.ApplicareSchedulers.getApplicareRunningReportQuartzScheduler(ApplicareSchedulers.java:140)
> at
> com.arcturus.reports.mailauto.MyContextListener$1.run(MyContextListener.java:81)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 23-May-2023 07:47:51.805
> INFO [Thread-18] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing
> ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8880"] 23-May-2023 07:47:52.131 INFO
> [Thread-18] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal
> Stopping service [Catalina] 23-May-2023 07:47:52.152 INFO [Thread-18]
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler
> ["http-nio-8880"] 23-May-2023 07:47:52.165 INFO [Thread-18]
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler
> ["http-nio-8880"]
> pplicareReportQuartzScheduler(ApplicareSchedulers.java:188)   at
> com.arcturus.reports.scheduler.ApplicareSchedulers.getApplicareRunningReportQuartzScheduler(ApplicareSchedulers.java:140)
> at
> com.arcturus.reports.mailauto.MyContextListener$1.run(MyContextListener.java:81)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Illegal access: this web application
> instance has been stopped already. Could not load
> [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy]. The following stack trace
> is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate
> the thread which caused the illegal access.   at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1375)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1226)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
> ... 9 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal
> access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could
> not load [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy]. The following
> stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to
> terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.     at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1385)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1373)
> ... 11 more

**Below is the service.bat file**

```
setlocal
set ARCTURUS_HOME=%CD%\..\..

set "SELF=%~dp0%service.bat"

set DEFAULT_SERVICE_NAME=ApplicareAdmin
set SERVICE_NAME=%DEFAULT_SERVICE_NAME%

set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"

rem Parse the arguments
if "x%1x" == "xx" goto displayUsage
set SERVICE_CMD=%1
shift
if "x%1x" == "xx" goto checkEnv
:checkUser
if "x%1x" == "x/userx" goto runAsUser
if "x%1x" == "x--userx" goto runAsUser
set SERVICE_NAME=%1
shift
if "x%1x" == "xx" goto checkEnv
if "x%1x" == "x--renamex" (
    set RENAME=%1
    shift
)
if "x%1x" == "xx" goto checkEnv
goto checkUser
:runAsUser
shift
if "x%1x" == "xx" goto displayUsage
set SERVICE_USER=%1
shift
runas /env /savecred /user:%SERVICE_USER% "%COMSPEC% /K \"%SELF%\" %SERVICE_CMD% %SERVICE_NAME%"
exit /b 0

rem Check the environment
:checkEnv

rem Guess CATALINA_HOME if not defined
if not "%CATALINA_HOME%" == "" goto gotHome
set "CATALINA_HOME=%cd%"
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\%DEFAULT_SERVICE_NAME%.exe" goto gotHome
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\%SERVICE_NAME%.exe" goto gotHome
rem CD to the upper dir
cd ..
set "CATALINA_HOME=%cd%"
:gotHome
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\%DEFAULT_SERVICE_NAME%.exe" (
    set "EXECUTABLE=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\%DEFAULT_SERVICE_NAME%.exe"
    goto okHome
)
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\%SERVICE_NAME%.exe" (
    set "EXECUTABLE=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\%SERVICE_NAME%.exe"
    goto okHome
)
if "%DEFAULT_SERVICE_NAME%"== "%SERVICE_NAME%" (
    echo The file %DEFAULT_SERVICE_NAME%.exe was not found...
) else (
    echo Neither the %DEFAULT_SERVICE_NAME%.exe file nor the %SERVICE_NAME%.exe file was found...
)
echo Either the CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly or
echo the incorrect service name has been used.
echo Both the CATALINA_HOME environment variable and the correct service name
echo are required to run this program.
exit /b 1
:okHome
cd "%CURRENT_DIR%"

rem Make sure prerequisite environment variables are set
if not "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" goto gotJdkHome
if not "%JRE_HOME%" == "" goto gotJreHome
echo Neither the JAVA_HOME nor the JRE_HOME environment variable is defined
echo Service will try to guess them from the registry.
goto okJavaHome
:gotJreHome
if not exist "%JRE_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto noJavaHome
goto okJavaHome
:gotJdkHome
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe" goto noJavaHome
rem Java 9 has a different directory structure
if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin\java.exe" goto preJava9Layout
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto noJavaHome
if not "%JRE_HOME%" == "" goto okJavaHome
set "JRE_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%"
goto okJavaHome
:preJava9Layout
if not "%JRE_HOME%" == "" goto okJavaHome
set "JRE_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%\jre"
goto okJavaHome
:noJavaHome
echo The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
echo This environment variable is needed to run this program
echo NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
exit /b 1
:okJavaHome
if not "%CATALINA_BASE%" == "" goto gotBase
set "CATALINA_BASE=%CATALINA_HOME%"
:gotBase

rem Java 9 no longer supports the java.endorsed.dirs
rem system property. Only try to use it if
rem JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS was explicitly set
rem or CATALINA_HOME/endorsed exists.
set ENDORSED_PROP=ignore.endorsed.dirs
if "%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" == "" goto noEndorsedVar
set ENDORSED_PROP=java.endorsed.dirs
goto doneEndorsed
:noEndorsedVar
if not exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\endorsed" goto doneEndorsed
set ENDORSED_PROP=java.endorsed.dirs
:doneEndorsed

rem Process the requested command
if /i %SERVICE_CMD% == install goto doInstall
if /i %SERVICE_CMD% == remove goto doRemove
if /i %SERVICE_CMD% == uninstall goto doRemove
echo Unknown parameter "%SERVICE_CMD%"
:displayUsage
echo.
echo Usage: service.bat install/remove [service_name [--rename]] [--user username]
exit /b 1

:doRemove
rem Remove the service
echo Removing the service '%SERVICE_NAME%' ...
echo Using CATALINA_BASE:    "%CATALINA_BASE%"

"%EXECUTABLE%" //DS//%SERVICE_NAME% ^
    --LogPath "%ARCTURUS_HOME%\logs"
if not errorlevel 1 goto removed
echo Failed removing '%SERVICE_NAME%' service
exit /b 1
:removed
echo The service '%SERVICE_NAME%' has been removed
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\%SERVICE_NAME%.exe" (
    rename "%SERVICE_NAME%.exe" "%DEFAULT_SERVICE_NAME%.exe"
    rename "%SERVICE_NAME%w.exe" "%DEFAULT_SERVICE_NAME%w.exe"
)
exit /b 0

:doInstall
rem Install the service
echo Installing the service '%SERVICE_NAME%' ...
echo Using CATALINA_HOME:    "%CATALINA_HOME%"
echo Using CATALINA_BASE:    "%CATALINA_BASE%"
echo Using JAVA_HOME:        "%JAVA_HOME%"
echo Using JRE_HOME:         "%JRE_HOME%"

rem Try to use the server jvm
set "JVM=%JRE_HOME%\bin\server\jvm.dll"
if exist "%JVM%" goto foundJvm
rem Try to use the client jvm
set "JVM=%JRE_HOME%\bin\client\jvm.dll"
if exist "%JVM%" goto foundJvm
echo Warning: Neither 'server' nor 'client' jvm.dll was found at JRE_HOME.
set JVM=auto
:foundJvm
echo Using JVM:              "%JVM%"

set "CLASSPATH=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\bootstrap.jar;%CATALINA_BASE%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
if not "%CATALINA_HOME%" == "%CATALINA_BASE%" set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"

if "%SERVICE_STARTUP_MODE%" == "" set SERVICE_STARTUP_MODE=auto
if "%JvmMs%" == "" set JvmMs=512
if "%JvmMx%" == "" set JvmMx=1024

if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\%DEFAULT_SERVICE_NAME%.exe" (
    if "x%RENAME%x" == "x--renamex" (
        rename "%DEFAULT_SERVICE_NAME%.exe" "%SERVICE_NAME%.exe"
        rename "%DEFAULT_SERVICE_NAME%w.exe" "%SERVICE_NAME%w.exe"
        set "EXECUTABLE=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\%SERVICE_NAME%.exe"
    )
)

"%EXECUTABLE%" //IS//%SERVICE_NAME% ^
    --Description "Applicare tunes applications, monitors transactions and self-detects problems. Get visibility to every business transaction, every application, everywhere." ^
    --DisplayName "%SERVICE_NAME%" ^
    --Install "%EXECUTABLE%" ^
    --LogPath "%ARCTURUS_HOME%\logs" ^
    --StdOutput "%ARCTURUS_HOME%\logs\applicare_service_out.log" ^
    --StdError "%ARCTURUS_HOME%\logs\applicare_service_err.log" ^
    --Classpath "%CLASSPATH%;%ARCTURUS_HOME%\bin\bootstrap.jar" ^
    --Jvm "%JVM%" ^
    --StartMode jvm ^
    --StopMode jvm ^
    --StartPath "%ARCTURUS_HOME%\server" ^
    --StopPath "%ARCTURUS_HOME%\server" ^
    --StartClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap ^
    --StopClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap ^
    --StartParams start ^
    --StopParams stop ^
    --JvmOptions "-Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME%;-Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE%;-D%ENDORSED_PROP%=%CATALINA_HOME%\endorsed;-Djava.io.tmpdir=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp;-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager;-Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties;-Dserver.name=ApplicareAdmin;-Darcturus_home=%ARCTURUS_HOME%;-Dsolr.solr.home=%ARCTURUS_HOME%\solr;-Dapplicare.admin=true;-Dspring.profiles.active=nosaml;%JvmArgs%" ^
    --JvmOptions9 "--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED#--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED#--add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED" ^
    --Startup "%SERVICE_STARTUP_MODE%" ^
    --JvmMs "%JvmMs%" ^
    --JvmMx "%JvmMx%"
if not errorlevel 1 goto installed
echo Failed installing '%SERVICE_NAME%' service
exit /b 1
:installed
echo The service '%SERVICE_NAME%' has been installed.
net start %SERVICE_NAME%
exit /b 0
```